# GPS Location Listener

Tags: android, gps

I am looking to get the below values just once.  How do I stop the listener?  I get the values, and then in `onLocationChanged()` the `removeUpdates()` method gives me a null pointer exception.  All this is called from a button click

```
 public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
             locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
                //editLocation.setText("");
                //pb.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        "Location changed: Lat: " + loc.getLatitude() + " Lng: "
                                + loc.getLongitude(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                String longitude = "Longitude: " + loc.getLongitude();
                //Log.v(TAG, longitude);
                String latitude = "Latitude: " + loc.getLatitude();
                //Log.v(TAG, latitude);

            /*------- To get city name from coordinates -------- */
                String cityName = null;
                String StreetName = null;
                Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getBaseContext(), Locale.getDefault());
                List<Address> addresses;
                            try {
                                locationManager=null;
                    addresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                            loc.getLongitude(), 1);
                    if (addresses.size() > 0)
                        System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getLocality());
                    cityName = addresses.get(0).getLocality();
                    if (addresses.size() > 0)
                        System.out.println(addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare());
                    StreetName=addresses.get(0).getThoroughfare();
                }
                catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                String s = longitude + "\n" + latitude + "\n\nMy Current City is: "
                        + cityName;
                //editLocation.setText(s);
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        "Location: " + s, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Toast.makeText(
                        getBaseContext(),
                        "Street Name: " + StreetName, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);

            }
```

button

```
  public void Punchout(View view) {
        boolean hasNetwrokProvider;
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Getting Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
              getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

      locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 3, locationListener);
```

Before OnCreate:

```
private LocationManager locationManager;
private LocationListener locationListener;
```

Comment: Show where you declare and initialize `locationManager`.

Comment: Just edited to reflect

Answer (score 0):

I see the problem.  You're creating local variables in the `Punchout()` method instead of using the instance variables defined in the Activity.

Just make sure that you're always using the instance variables, so that they will be accessible in `onLocationChanged()`

```
public void Punchout(View view) {
    boolean hasNetwrokProvider;
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Getting Location", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

  /* These lines created local variables:
  LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager)
          getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  LocationListener locationListener = new MyLocationListener();
  */

  //use the instance variables instead:
  locationManager = (LocationManager)
          getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
  locationListener = new MyLocationListener();

  locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 3000, 3, locationListener);
}
```